# Can't find formatter specific to js-2016 inline HTML

Tags: javascript, formatting, file-format

Have some need to keep my JS files formatted in github repo and among peoples.
Have such bloc in one file

```html
    render() {
        const { application, services, iWantTos, stages, actions, gameplan, dispatch } = this.props;

```
    return (
         <div className={styles.root}>
       <div className={styles.hero}>

          <img
            alt="A staircase up to the next level of your startup."
            src={`${imgPath}mobile-landingPage-staircase.png`}
            srcSet={`
              ${imgPath}mobile-landingPage-staircase@2x.png 2x,
              ${imgPath}mobile-landingPage-staircase@3x.png 3x
            `}
            className={styles.heroImage}
          />
```

```

The second `div` line is improperly aligned as you see. It should be nested, but it does not. I've slightly modified typescript formatter, but this does not help, Any suggestion?

Comment: Try https://github.com/prettier/prettier, it supports JSX, which is the format that resembles the most to your code.

Comment: Wow great! Thank you for your answer. Will install and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yuriy636 I found the solution: github.com/prettier/prettier supports JSX